# numbers just before closing bracket in CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

The below is from a WP theme stylesheet I'm working with. I do not know why there is a **"1014"** just before the closing bracket. There are a few instances of this throughout the theme's CSS–*different* numbers–but always just before the closing bracket.

```
.elementor-element .elementor-column
{
    padding: 20px !important;1014
}
```

I just simply don't know what this is, if these are typos etc.? I thought it may be related to page ID, but there is no page ID associated with that number.

Comment: This is a syntax error. CSS validator returned a Parse Error for this code snippet

Comment: @AdamP. I guess he is asking why 1014 was added to his code by the theme.

Comment: I feel the theme PHP files were edited and the generated CSS is appended with the "unintended text".

Comment: @m4n0 I think the developer of this theme copied this snippet from somewhere and somehow also copied the line numbers

Comment: @AdamP and m4n0, thank you for answering my question — I sincerely appreciate it. So basically, I'm not crazy, this is in fact "unintended text", and not some CSS syntax I was unaware of. I guess I was surprised to find it where I did, so I thought perhaps there was something to it. I concur, I think this is the line number it was on. Many thanks.

Comment: How do I mark this as solved/answered?

Comment: @NickJones You can not accept a comment as an answer

Comment: You can write that answer and mark it or we can close it as a "typo" question.